# Modeling Help and Dealing with Ngon's

Tags: modeling, topology

I am modeling a soda can and have found it increasingly difficult to deal with the high number of vertices as I collapse towards to center of the mesh. I was wondering if anyone had any advice to deal with this Ngon. Especially when trying to create finer details around where the tab should be. Still quite new to 3D modeling so any advice is very helpful, thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to avoid elongated faces. Also look into techniques for reducing the number of connecting points, read the "loop reduction flows" section in https://topologyguides.com/

Comment: also, you have a lot of edge loops, you should try to work with much less, at least as long as you can use modifiers like Subdivision Surface